# PySpark withCoumn Function to pull out certain fields

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am trying to select certain fields from my dataframe.

The folloiwng printSchema() shows the fields from my dataframe

The code is being written in PySpark

```
df_log.printSchema()



root
 |-- load_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Feed_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Feed_source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Feed_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Load_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Duration_of_load: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Rows_loaded: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Error message: string (nullable = true)
```

I only want 'load_id' and 'Feed_name' from the dataset, so I attempted the following:

```
df_log.withColumn(col(load_id), col(Feed_name))
```

But I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'col' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):

NameError: name 'col' is not defined
```

This is being run on Azure Synapse with Apache Spark Pools.

I shouldn't have to define 'col'

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `select` instead.

```
df_log.select('load_id', 'Feed_name')
```

Comment: Dohg!.. Thanks @jay